# Devise, CanCan + Cantango

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I'm following the quickstart guide here: https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango/wiki/Quickstart

I'm trying to optionally define guest user logic - I have the Guest user model defined, as well as user and role permits.  I'm getting the following error when calling user_can?

```
Model <Guest> has no #email as defined in CanTango.config.user.unique_key_field
```

I've narrowed it down to the fact that the user.unique_key_field must be defined; however this is just a guest, and as such wouldn't have provided an email (nor should they have to).  Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is not.

For my part, I just added a defaut guest address in an `email` method :

```
def email
  'guest@mysite.com'
end
```

It seems to be the recommanded way to go in Cantango Wiki's [simple scenario](https://github.com/kristianmandrup/cantango/wiki/Simple-scenario) (which also mentions releasing a `:default_guest_user` to spare us the trouble, but I don't think it is implemented yet)